# No packet loss in sending packets over local UDP sockets

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

Is it normal that there will be no packet losses in a UDP client-server if both are on the same machine? I'm currently calculating packet loss by taking the difference between the bytes obtained from the `sendto` and `recvfrom` functions on the client side ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be *very* surprised if there was any packet loss in such a case. But on the other hand you use the wrong way to calculate any loss.

Remember that UDP is a *packet oriented* protocol, which means that what you send will be a packet, and what you receive will be a packet, and there will be no difference in the size of what you send and receive. If you send a 512-byte packet, the receiver will always receive the full 512-byte packet, or nothing at all.

That means you should count the number of times you call `sendto`, and compare the number of times that `recvfrom` returns with a packet.

Comment: Can you explain the last part of your answer a bit more ?

Comment: @Jarvis Like I said, if you send a X byte packet, then the other end will receive the full X byte packet, or nothing at all. The packet loss is counted by taking the number of `sendto` calls, minus the number of `recvfrom` calls that return with a value larger than zero.

Comment: But inside the client side program, we have two methods, one `sendto()` which sends the packet and the other `recvfrom()`, which indicates that the server echoed this packet back, won't this guarantee that the packet successfully got echoed if `recvfrom()` returns positive value ? In short, on which side should I do this calculation, server side or client side ?

Comment: @Jarvis If all the server does is "echoing" the packets it receives, you could have a packet-loss on the packet you send to the server, or of the packet sent back from the server, so there are two chances of loss in a round-trip. So you need to count sends and receives on *both* the client and server to be accurate.

Comment: I'm sending a packet a given number of times using a for loop, and then the program sleeps for given time interval at end of the loop body, and inside the for loop, there is one sendto and one recvfrom, so you mean to say take the difference between the number of 'successful' sendto()'s and recvfrom()'s on both sides ?

Comment: Even on the local machine, you can easily get packet loss if you send data faster than the receiver can pick them up. When the internal buffers overflow, UDP provides no flow-control, and packets drop.

Comment: My client code : http://ideone.com/jZpDiD Please look at the for loop where I get the bytes received and send using the system calls, `recvfrom` and `sendto` ? How should I do the calculation for packet loss here ? @nos